# keycode and fromCharCode in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I wrote the following code (using jQuery) to show the pressed key.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  $("div").text("Key:" + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase());
  return false;
});
```

This code works in normal alphabet characters (q,w,e,r...).
But when I press non alphabet keys (like ']'), an incorrect character is shown.

ex: ',' -> ¼, ']' -> ý

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event and [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) property.

jQuery normalizes the keycodes, and stores the variable in `event.which`. The `keypress` event's `which` property is the only reliable value for `String.fromCharCode`.

The `event.keyCode` property may not be equal to the `event.charCode` or `event.which` properties.

For non-printable characters, `event.which` has a value of zero, contrary to `event.keyCode`. That's why you're seeing weird characters.

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var charCode = e.which;
    if (!charCode) { // <-- charCode === 0
        return;// return false, optionally
    }
    $("div").text("Key:" + String.fromCharCode(charCode).toLowerCase());
    return false; // Or e.preventDefault(); and/or e.stopPropagation()
}).keyup(function(e) {
    // Key is lifted, do something
});
```

Comment: But I want to know whether the key is down or not, so I have to use keydown and keyup events.

Comment: @fishpotato `keypress` is fired right after the `keydown` event. What's the application of your code?

Comment: I'm writing a synthesizer. I would like turn on / off sound by key state.

Comment: @fishpotato Than the `keypress` event suits very well, especially since you're using `return false` (=e.preventDefault()`). The `keydown` event can be replaced with the `keypress` event, in this case. I'll update my answer with a demo.

Comment: But how can I turn off sound when the key become up? I appreciate your answer. :)

Comment: @fishpotato Also bind a `keyup` event, as seen in my answer. Warning: You have to account for a rare condition. The user may click outside the window, causing the `keyup` event not to be detected. If this is an important issue, you can add a small `setTimeout` to the `keypress` method, which clears the state. To prevent race conditions, this timeout has to be cleared in the `keyup` event as well.

Comment: Your code works well in `keyPress` event, but unfortunately a wrong character returns in `keyUp` event. I can detect key down of `;` key by `keyPress` event with your code, but cannot detect key up of `;` in `keyUp` event. :(

Comment: @fishpotato Only the `keypress` is capable of detecting the right keycodes. Is the character important, or the key? You can also detect the key modifiers by checking the `e.altKey`, `e.shiftKey` and `e.ctrlKey` properties of the event. They're `true` if the key is pressed, `false` otherwise.

Comment: The character is important because I want to use PC keyboard as a musical keyboard. (When you press `a`, `C` note is played, `s` for `D` note, `d` for `E`...) I consider to use only alphabet keys, but if there is a way to do, I would like to use `:` and `"` for higher notes.

Comment: @fishpotato If you want to be 100% certain about the keys, you can set up a `keydown` and `keypress` event for configuration. The `keypress` event is fired right after the `keydown` event. So, you can grab the `keyCode`, `shiftKey` (alt/ctlKey?) at the `keydown` event, and bind it to the charCode using the `keypress` event. Once you've mapped all necessary keys, you can remove the `keydown` event (optionally modify the `keypress` event).

Comment: What to do on Chrome for Android?  The KeyPress event doesn't fire reliably on Chrome for Android.